# Set value of hidden input inside form HtmlUnit

Tags: java, forms, input, hidden, htmlunit

(HtmlUnit/Java/NetBeans 7.3)

How do you set the value for hidden inputs inside a form. I have a form, an it has the hiddens. No need to add hiddens.

I have the values and I just need to set those inputs with such values.

Thanks everyone!

HTML code

```
<tr id="theRowprof_1_54066" style="display:table-row;">
<td valign="top">
<input type="text" readonly="" onclick="buscaProf('79FA9300D2DC4BDE');" value="STAFF" size="6" name="p_profesor_1_54066">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="p_profesor_pidm_1_54066">
<input type="hidden" value="100" name="p_responsabilidad_1_54066">
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: can you provide the source code of the hidden input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not provided the source code so i m providing the code assuming that hidden input contain ID attribute.

```
HtmlHiddenInput hidden  = (HtmlHiddenInput) page.getElementById("Hidden_Id");
hidden.setValueAttribute("Updated_Value");
```

Comment: HtmlHiddenInput hidden  = (HtmlHiddenInput)page.getElementByName("p_profesor_pidm_1_54066");
       hidden.setValueAttribute("Updated_Value");Please try this change.If it work let me knw